# wingpanel is using almost 100GB of virtual memory

Tags: release-loki, wingpanel

Just randomly noticed that wingpanel is using 98GB of virtual memory.

[image: gnome system monitor screenshot]

Restarted it with "kill -HUP", it used 97GB upon restart.

OS version is 0.4.1. I'm relatively new to this so any input is appreciated.

Thanks.